# Spring Boot. Генерация war и запуск в TomCat

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, tomcat

Ситуация: использую `Spring Boot`. При запуске из под `IDE`, как я понимаю поднимается встроенный TomCat и в нем уже разворачивается приложение, все нормально работает, можно быстро протестировать итд...в этом как я понимаю и основное удобство `Spring Boot`.

Теперь хочу задеплоить приложение на боевой сервер. Для этого генерирую war, который кстати прилично весит, и пытаюсь его развернуть. Получаю вот такую ошибку:

> FAIL - Application at context path /test could not be started FAIL -
>   Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/test]]

При запуске сервера в командной строке так же  вижу слово SPRING в ascii art, что меня и наторлкнуло на мысль - а он случайно при развертывании моего приложения не поднимает на сервере сервер, может в этом и есть ошибка?

Может быть war надо каким то по другому методом генерировать? Сейчас генерирую командой `package`.

Вот pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Кто использует `Spring Boot` подскажите пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка, может я что то принципиально неверно делаю?

Comment: Сделай по туториалу https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/

Comment: @rvit34 да по его туториал качал, запускал, работает, отличие от не работающего, в версии `spring boot` и в наличии security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
<!-- ... -->
<packaging>war</packaging>
<!-- ... -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```

А так же провешь вообще если запускаеться твой проект. Собери его в `jar` файл и запусти из терминала `java -jar file_name.jar`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Comment: после добавления `<scope>provided</scope>` ничего не изменилось, попробовал запустить сгенерированный jar, встроенный сервер поднялся.

Comment: @droid ты добавил именно зависимость `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` ?

Comment: да, верно, просто не так написал, добавил зависимость полностью, после этом выходной war поднабрал несколько мб

Comment: Пробема в том как запускаеться приложение проверь логи `logs/catalina.out`

Comment: судя по логам, такая ошибка `Annotation-specified bean name 'mainController' for bean class [***.MainController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [***.MainController]`

Comment: В контексте 2 бина 'mainController', измени имя контролера  который будет создан на @Controller("myNewController")

Comment: исправил, задеплоил, странные вещи теперь происходят, вот теперь дефолтная страница томкэта не отображается и все что до этого было задеплоино

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55404/discussion-between-gvart-and-droid).